# Theoretically, are DATE and TIME two different variables?

Tags: data-processing, data-quality

I’m curious to find out if, in terms of tidy data principles, a column containing “date and time” ( 1/1/21 11:31) would be considered as a single variable or tow separate ones?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp:

An important difference is that DATETIME represents a date (as found in a calendar) and a time (as can be observed on a wall clock), while TIMESTAMP represents a well defined point in time.